# Getting KeyError: 61 while iterating through the rows

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataset, one of my columns is `Name` the other that I created is `IncStr`. If the name in the column includes `Rev`, I want to convert the `IncStr` to 1 which consists of all zeros. To do that, I have written the below code but getting a `KeyError: 61`:

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if ((df['Name'].str.contains('Rev'))[i] == True):
               df['IncStr'] == 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in pandas is best avoid loops if possible - here convert boolean mask to integers - `True, False` to `1,0`:

```
df['IncStr'] = df['Name'].str.contains('Rev').astype(int)
```